# ECG signal QRS detection with wfdb

Tags: python-3.x, signal-processing

I am using the wfdb 3.1.1 for QRS detection in ECG signals. My code goes like this -

```
record,fields=wfdb.io.rdsamp(r'D:\Research\Biomedical Image Proc\\ECG-Apnea records\a01',sampfrom=200,sampto=700) 
wfdb.plot_items(signal=record,title='ECG Apnea data for patient 1',return_fig=True)   
xqrs=processing.xqrs_detect(sig=record[:,0],fs=fields['fs'])     
print(xqrs)
```

However, after I plot the detected peaks on the ECG signal, I notice that some of the T peaks are detected instead of the R peak. Is this a recognized issue with the wfdb QRS detection class? The reason I need this is because I need to slice the beats after this. Without proper peaks, the results won't be promising.

Answer (score 2):

Please, note that detecting QRS in ECG data is non trivial task, and still many research are conducted to improve the accuracy of detection algorithms. The questions are:

- How many QRS detection failure compared to good detection do you obtain (or approximate percentage of wrong detections), and how does this value compare with usual QRS detection algorithms?
- did you try to perform the detection with different parameters? If no, I recommend visiting the [online documentation](https://wfdb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/processing.html#module-wfdb.processing) where you can find plenty of case-dependent fine-tuning settings (in the `Conf` class for `XQRS` configuration) like QRS width, max and min values, etc.